# How to combine two large tables and export them to .txt file?

Tags: export, list-manipulation

I have two large tables. I shall post only 2 rows out of 100+. I shall name the first table `blabla` and the elements are:

```
blabla = {{1.`, 0.0118897`, 0.0218102`, 0.0166538`, 0.026621`, 
    0.0195213`, 0.0295166`, 0.0171602`, 0.0271323`, 0.0218905`, 
    0.0319091`, 0.0194651`, 0.0294599`, 0.0166805`, 0.026648`, 
    0.0204106`, 0.0304147`, 0.0228323`, 0.0328601`, 0.021254`, 
    0.0312663`, 0.0233098`, 0.0333423`, 0.021873`, 0.0318914`, 
    0.0174677`, 0.0274429`, 0.0188054`, 0.0287937`, 0.0219893`, 
    0.0320088`, 0.0309231`, 0.0410302`, 0.0285016`, 0.0385849`, 
    0.0296551`, 0.0397497`, 0.0350313`, 0.0451787`, 0.0304206`, 
    0.0405227`, 0.0428235`, 0.0530473`, 0.0432169`, 0.0534446`, 
    0.03005`, 0.0401486`, 0.0286906`, 0.0387758`, 0.0304793`, 
    0.040582`, 0.0804419`, 0.0910345`, 0.142272`, 0.153471`, 
    0.160546`, 0.171924`}, {2.`, 0.0150861`, 0.025038`, 0.0196577`, 
    0.0296543`, 0.0214633`, 0.0314777`, 0.0205533`, 0.0305587`, 
    0.0239663`, 0.0340052`, 0.0222613`, 0.0322834`, 0.0208354`, 
    0.0308436`, 0.0234556`, 0.0334895`, 0.0244662`, 0.0345099`, 
    0.0252611`, 0.0353126`, 0.0252723`, 0.035324`, 0.0250053`, 
    0.0350544`, 0.0220828`, 0.0321032`, 0.0221404`, 0.0321613`, 
    0.0256944`, 0.0357503`, 0.0317988`, 0.0419144`, 0.0336531`, 
    0.043787`, 0.03152`, 0.0416329`, 0.0356098`, 0.0457629`, 
    0.0360809`, 0.0462385`, 0.0444764`, 0.0547163`, 0.0501084`, 
    0.0604036`, 0.0329392`, 0.043066`, 0.0364718`, 0.0466333`, 
    0.0359922`, 0.046149`, 0.0869363`, 0.0975925`, 0.143037`, 
    0.154243`, 0.199699`, 0.21146`}};
```

while the second table is

```
neki = {{0.0202148`, 0.0274192`, 0.0207453`, 0.0262675`, 0.0189993`, 
    0.0233971`, 0.022678`, 0.0285582`, 0.0209791`, 0.0253666`, 
    0.0213924`, 0.0263567`, 0.0260517`, 0.0329767`, 0.0223663`, 
    0.0273434`, 0.0196478`, 0.0236058`, 0.0259541`, 0.0315261`, 
    0.0201568`, 0.0241432`, 0.0219558`, 0.0265508`, 0.0258081`, 
    0.0323964`, 0.019427`, 0.0240745`, 0.0214446`, 0.0259115`, 
    0.0193406`, 0.0223116`, 0.0274793`, 0.0320205`, 0.0185941`, 
    0.0215596`, 0.0186161`, 0.0211728`, 0.0260151`, 0.0300705`, 
    0.0218959`, 0.0244066`, 0.0310664`, 0.0345995`, 0.0150838`, 
    0.0174611`, 0.0252581`, 0.0294076`, 0.0162781`, 0.0188112`, 
    0.0319529`, 0.034044`, 0.0404893`, 0.0421196`, 0.040583`, 
    0.0420639`}, {0.0227813`, 0.0293923`, 0.0225488`, 0.0277362`, 
    0.0199277`, 0.0241689`, 0.0248315`, 0.0303233`, 0.0219581`, 
    0.0261947`, 0.0228869`, 0.0276024`, 0.029134`, 0.0355`, 
    0.0239875`, 0.0287053`, 0.0203436`, 0.0241971`, 0.028312`, 
    0.0335241`, 0.0209943`, 0.0248577`, 0.0234862`, 0.0278493`, 
    0.0290378`, 0.0350636`, 0.0210898`, 0.0254561`, 0.0231937`, 
    0.0273992`, 0.0196151`, 0.0225536`, 0.0298824`, 0.034137`, 
    0.0191751`, 0.0220705`, 0.0187708`, 0.0213111`, 0.028356`, 
    0.0321484`, 0.0223199`, 0.0247937`, 0.0334858`, 0.0368208`, 
    0.015799`, 0.0180922`, 0.0285108`, 0.0322872`, 0.0177035`, 
    0.0200765`, 0.0332491`, 0.0352824`, 0.0406024`, 0.0422301`, 
    0.0455114`, 0.0469092`}};
```

What I want it so add the columns of `neki` table at the of `blabla` table. I tried to combine them with the following code

```
FinalOutput = Join[blabla, neki, 2];
```

Now here is the catch I don't understand. If I export that `FinalOutput` like that:

```
Export["results_output.txt", 
  StringReplace[ToString[TableForm[FinalOutput]], "\n\n" -> "\n"]];
```

I get some weird spacing. The columns are not aligned as they should be. I attached the result to this code in the dropbox map. Yet if I type `finalOutput//TableForm` in mathematica the output is perfect - just the way I want it to be. So I assume something is wrong with my export code, but what?

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you were to provide a small data set directly in the question. The code you show cannot be evaluated due to that, and downloading data and code from other locations can be awkward. Your export line seems somewhat convoluted.

Comment: @YvesKlett Good point, I have edited the OP.

Comment: It appears to be a whitespace problem. When you convert 1 to a string as opposed to 0.1234 to a string, both have different string lengths. I would convert the individual entries to strings and add whitespace so that everyone is the same length.

Comment: @Wintermute I'm not really sure how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the implementation of Wintermute's idea (see comments in OP question) :

```
stringTable = Map[ToString, finalOutput, {2}];
maxStringLength = Max[Flatten[Map[StringLength, stringTable, {2}]]];
finalOutput300 = 
  Map[RightComposition[Characters, 
    PadRight[#, maxStringLength, " "] &, StringJoin], 
   stringTable, {2}];
Export["results_output300.txt", 
  StringReplace[
   ToString[TableForm[finalOutput300, TableSpacing -> {1, 1}]], 
   "\n\n" -> "\n"]];
```

Verification :

```
fileContent = ReadList["results_output300.txt", String];
header = fileContent[[1]] // StringLength // 
     Table[Mod[i, 10], {i, 1, #}] & // (ToString /@ # &) // StringJoin;
Prepend[fileContent, header] // 
  MapThread[
    List, {{"column number :", "file data :", "file data :"}, #}] & //
  Grid[#, ColumnWidths -> All] &
```

It gives a very large table. The beginning is :

[image]

and the end is :

[image]

The first line is just a numerotation of the characters. One can see that each number in the data lines begins at position 1, from the beginning until the end of the table. Each column of data has the same size : 10 characters. It was not the case in OP's code and that was the problem.

Comment: Hmm.. I get the same thing using your verifiaction code, yet the exported file doesn't look like that. I prepared a screen shot of the exported file I get. It is available [HERE](http://www4.slikomat.com/13/1220/26o-mathem.png)

Comment: @skrat This is because Notepad introduce somme carriage-returns which doesn't exist in the original file. If you use Wordpad and desactivate "automatic carriage return" you don't have the problem.

Comment: True! Works perfectly. Thanks to both of you (including Wintermute!).